# Protractor webdriver exception while run in chrome and IE

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor

I am trying to run protractor test case in Windows 32bit machine. webdriver starts well. But when run basic conf.js it says below error

> Driver info: driver version: unknown

I've set up node path, npm path, protractor path, java path in my system environmental variable.

While i try to create session using [local url](http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html) , It says

> Unable to create new session

error. [image: Response from the chrome]

Comment: Are you providing seleniumServer URL in protractor conf.js file? If so , what is the value you are providing?

Comment: Hi, This is the url in config, { seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' }